# Average between elements of RDD of rows

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an RDD of many Rows (namely, `RDDmacReturns`) that follows this structure:

```
case class macReturns (macAddress: String, 
                       hourReturns: Long, 
                       threeHoursReturns: Long,
                       sixHoursReturns: Long, 
                       halfDailyReturns: Long, 
                       dailyReturns: Long,
                       threeDailyReturns: Long, 
                       weeklyReturns: Long, 
                       biWeeklyReturns: Long, 
                       threeWeeklyReturns: Long, 
                       monthlyReturns: Long)
```

so, for example, a row of that RDD would be like:

`macReturns(a2:b2:c3:d3:f4:c5,3,4,1,0,3,4,3,5,1,7)`

macAddresses have already been grouped so they are all distinct.

Now, I have to create a new RDD with a single row, doing transformations/actions on `RDDmacReturns`, that follows the same aforementioned structure (case class MacReturns) and contains a fixed chosen (fake) macAddress and the average of each field calculated between the elements of RDDmacReturns, like this:

```
macReturns(00:00:00:00:00:00,
           averageHourReturns,
           averageThreeHoursReturns,
           averageSixHoursReturns,
           averageHalfDailyReturns,
           averageDailyReturns,
           averageThreeDailyReturns,
           averageWeeklyReturns,
           averageBiWeeklyReturns,
           averageThreeWeeklyReturns,
           averageMonthlyReturns)
```

To sum up, I need a function that applied to RDDmacReturns, returns RDDaverageReturns, that contains a single row (described just above)

Thanks for the help

Comment: You probably want `aggregate` and http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.util.StatCounter

Comment: can't you just use [colStats](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-statistics.html) ?

Comment: @mtoto, I didn't know of that - thanks (not the OP).

Comment: @mtoto me neither, now i'ill try to manipulate my data and use colStats to calculate mean for each column. thanks

Comment: @mtoto mission accomplished, thanks. It was very easy just following the example from the documentation you linked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `colStats()` which returns an instance of `MultivariateStatisticalSummary`, containing among other things the column-wise `mean`. Here's a reproducible example similar to your problem:

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.stat.{MultivariateStatisticalSummary, Statistics}

val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("id1",1,2,3,4),
  ("id2",3,5,1,5),
  ("id3",3,0,9,8),
  ("id4",4,4,1,2)))
// First we convert to RDD of dense vectors 
val rdd_dense = rdd.map(x => Vectors.dense(x._2, x._3, x._4, x._5))
// Attain colStats and grab the mean
val summary: MultivariateStatisticalSummary = Statistics.colStats(rdd_dense)
println(summary.mean) 
[2.75,2.75,3.5000000000000004,4.75]
```